# Calling a C# function with the <map> tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, imagemap

I have this piece of code on an image within my web page:

```
<map name="mapWouldYouRather">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,460,260" alt="GuessBlue" href="Index.aspx"/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="470,0,930,260" alt="GuessRed" href="Index.aspx"/>
</map>
```

Is there any way call a C# function when I click on one of the areas instead of linking it to a specific web page?

Answer (score 2):

You could use onclick instead of href and call a javascript function which make a GET or POST request to the server.

```
<map name="mapWouldYouRather">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,460,260" alt="GuessBlue" onclick="myJsFunction()"/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="470,0,930,260" alt="GuessRed" onclick="myJsFunction()"/>
</map>
```